# Make a normal-looking project tree view in Qt Creator(VS)

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2017, qt-creator, clion

I'm looking for a way to make a normal looking tree view for a project that includes a lot of modules, static libraries, and several executable projects.

For example, there are 10 static libraries, about 50 modules, and if I open the project tree, for example, I will see only the subprojects I need. In cmake, specify that only what is needed is displayed.
Can anyone tell me how this can be done for any IDE that supports cmake?